# Is there a solution to the differences between listings and verbatim

Tags: listings, verbatim

My code is here,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstnewenvironment{code}
{\lstset{language={Matlab},
    lineskip=-1pt,
    belowskip=3pt,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=2.2em,%
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,%
    basicstyle=\bf\tt\color{black},%
    keywordstyle=\bf\tt\color{black},%
    identifierstyle=\bf\tt\color{black},%
    commentstyle=\bf\tt\color{black},%
    %backgroundcolor=\color{gray!3},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible}}
{}

\begin{document}
This is example of listings.
\begin{code}
    / sqrt(5)   1 \
    | ------- + - |
    |   2       2 |
    |             |
    | 1   sqrt(5) |
    | - - ------- |
    \ 2      2    /
\end{code}

This is verbatim example.
\begin{verbatim}
    / sqrt(5)   1 \
    | ------- + - |
    |   2       2 |
    |             |
    | 1   sqrt(5) |
    | - - ------- |
    \ 2      2    /
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Using XelaTeX but the result is

[image]

I want to get the same result. How to do?

Comment: Please give the OP time to react. Closing after 30 min is a little bit too fast, I think ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).